# Stacking Shelves with Overhang

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, statics

I want to stack some boxes which are 14" x 10" with some 12" records inside. This means that there will be a 2" overhang outside of each box.

I know that to have an item to balance on a edge 50% of an item needs to be supported. So I think I'm safe to load the boxes in this way.

If I were to stack boxes loaded in this way on top of each other is there a limit to how high they can go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the standard answer to this problem is usually given in terms of harmonic series,
(see for instance [this page at MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BookStackingProblem.html)) which results in stack looking like this:

[image: Harmonic stack]

I would like to share the nonstandard answer I found following one of the MathWorld links.
A whole new class of solutions was found in the paper by Paterson and Zwick:

> Paterson, Mike, and Uri Zwick. *Overhang*. Proceedings of the seventeenth annual ACM-SIAM symposium on Discrete algorithm. ACM, 2006. [arXiv:0710.2357](http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.2357).

The paper is quite accessible, so I suggest to have a look, but the main idea
 could be easily understood by looking at some of the solutions for various number of shelves:

[image]

So, by discarding assumption that only one shelf could be placed per level we
are able to produce much more solutions: overhang now scales like $c\,n^{1/3}$ with number of shelves, instead of $\frac 12 \ln n$ for harmonic series solution.

Comment: Does the OP intend to offset each box from the one below?  I read the question as dealing with a simple vertical stack with some of the contents sticking out the front of each box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was intending to just stack them vertically, however, reading the answer and links I believe answers my question.

Comment: I believe the answer in the limit of thin shelves is the log curve.

Comment: Related video explanation: https://youtu.be/1_DOzuaBE84