# Find maximum number of bricks that can be placed over each other

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics

The problem involves placing the maximum number of bricks over one another before the system falls off. Each brick is displaced with respect to one in contact by distance $d$. The mass of each brick is $m$. I have to find the maximum number of bricks I can place in the above manner.

I am trying to place the bricks this way:

```
xxxxxx
  xxxxxx
    xxxxxx
      xxxxxx
```

I am a little rusty on my mechanics problem solving, so a bit unsure how to proceed. I think I have to solve this by balancing the torques but not sure about what point and what kind of forces I have to include in the calculation. I can find the centre of mass of the system but then what forces will be considered?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I see that it is marked duplicate but it is not. The linked thread is finding the maximum overhang with N bricks, mine is different.

Comment: Is a brick finite in height?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stacking Shelves with Overhang](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91472/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hanging a brick free over an edge by stacking them](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107484)

Comment: Related interesting video: https://youtu.be/1_DOzuaBE84

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your construction to be stable, the center of mass of all but the first brick must not lie outside your base area, otherwise there would be a torque around the edge of the first brick, knocking your whole tower over. With the width of a brick $w$ and the shift distance $d$ per brick, we get
$$ x_{\text{com}} = \frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} d \cdot n \overset{!}{=} \frac{w}{2}\\[4ex]
\frac{1}{N-1}\frac{(N-1) N}{2} d = \frac{w}{2}\\[4ex]
N = \left\lfloor\frac{w}{d}\right\rfloor$$
$N$ is the total number of bricks you can place (including the base). In the last line, you will want to round down, since this will be the last brick you can put on without knocking the whole thing over.

Comment: I arrived at this same formula by a different mathematical method (still assuming the COM of the stacked bricks must like above the base brick), so +1 from me. Interesting that the problem mentions brick mass, which seems irrelevant, and does not mention brick width, which seems crucial.

Comment: Maybe mass could play a part? $r\times F$, $F=mg$, so if the bricks can have different masses you maybe can build it further? Just a guess.

Comment: Of course if the bricks had different masses, this would influence the position of the center of mass. However, in this question they cancel out.

Comment: My point was the mass seems irrelevant so long as all bricks are identical (actually, the base brick can have a different mass than those above it)

Comment: My reply was intended for Emil, not you @electronpusher :)