What is the maximum displacement at which a series of blocks can be displaced vertically?
This is a really simple question that I've been thinking. The statement is as following:
Consider you have a series of blocks, each of length $l$, width $w$, height $h$, and mass $m$ wich is evenly distributed across the entire block. There is the force of gravity. Imagine some surface that is totally flat, in which we place our block in $n=1$, where $n$ is the index for the number of blocks used.
We are going to define some quantities $\delta l_n$, $\delta w_n$, for each $n$ with one really simple condition:

$\delta l_n$ is defined as the displacement along the axis of $l$  the most upper block in the system has with the block that's beneath it, with the condition that the entire system of blocks is at equilibrium (no blocks fall).
The same thing happens with the axis along $w$.
Obviously, the displacements do not act on $n=1$ (only one block) and $n=0$ (no blocks).

With these conditions, I want to ask two questions:

Is there any function that relates $n$ to the displacement at $n$?
If so, how does the height $h$ and the mass $m$ of the blocks affect the final displacement?

Here I post a diagram for orientation:

As I have already said, with "maximum" I refer to the maximum length $\delta l_n$ and $\delta w_n$ can take without gravity letting the system of blocks collapse.

This question could really use a diagram.

I did that, thanks for the advice!

Block/card/book/domino stacking problem. Previously.

Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91472/123208

I remember such a problem, the displacement of cubes placed one on another was only in one direction. The total displacement could be arbitrarily large, and maximum displacements formed the harmonic series, if I remember correctly. Maybe I'll be able to add details later.
EDIT (Dec 7,2024): See discussion and references at https://math.dartmouth.edu/~pw/papers/maxover.pdf

Thanks a lot! I will take a look at your link!

Here's a version of the harmonic series I raytraced a couple of decades ago https://i.sstatic.net/CU1am3gr.jpg
